# Extracting a word from string from n rows and apend that word as a new col in R

Tags: r, string, extract

I have got a data set that contains 3 columns and has 15565 observations. one of the columns has got several words in the same row.
what i am looking to do is to extract a particular word from each row and append it to a new column (i will have 4 cols in total)
the problem is that the word that i am looking for are not the same and they are not always on the same position.
here is an extract of my DS:

`x     y              z
  1    T    3C00652722 (T558799A)
  2    T    NA >> MSP: T0578836A & 3C03024632
  3    T    T0579010A, 3C03051500, EAET03051496
  4    U    T0023231A > MSP: T0577506A & 3C02808556
  8    U    (T561041A C72/59460)>POPMigr.T576447A,C72/221816*3C00721502`

I am looking to extract all the words that start with `3C`and are 10 characters long and then append the to a new col so it looks like this:

`x     y              z                                    R

  1    T    3C00652722 (T558799A)                     3C00652722 
  2    T    NA >> MSP: T0578836A & 3C03024632         3C03024632
  3    T    T0579010A, 3C03051500, EAET03051496       3C03051500
  4    U    T0023231A > MSP: T0577506A & 3C02808556   3C02808556
  8    U    >POPMigr.T576447A,C72/221816*3C00721502   3C00721502`

i have tried using the stringr gprep libraries with no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
df1$R <- str_extract(df1$z, "\\b3C[^, ]{8}")
df1$R
#[1] "3C00652722" "3C03024632" "3C03051500" "3C02808556" "3C00721502"
```

Comment: And I think this is preferable to using `gsub`, which doesn't handle nicely the case where the input might not match the pattern.  `str_extract` would return `NA`, which is a decent placeholder for a non match +1.

Comment: @akrun you are a GOD mate! thanks you so much! i have been banging my head for the last 24 hours trying to make this work!

Comment: @RaulGonzales  Glad to know that it helped.  I am just an ordinary guy who got passionate in programming through constant practice...

Comment: @akrun An ordinary guy?? I don't think so :) ([this guy too](https://twitter.com/richierocks/status/796625158828150784)). Anyway, your help is very important for the SO community. Many thanks guy!

Answer (score 2):

While [akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) solution is the simple and elegant way, just for the sake I am posting another solution based on `stringr` library and `substring` method.

```
library(stringr)

x <- c(1,2,3,4,8)
y <- c('T','T','T','U','U')
z <- c('3C00652722 (T558799A)', 'NA >> MSP: T0578836A & 3C03024632', 'T0579010A, 3C03051500, EAET03051496',
   'T0023231A > MSP: T0577506A & 3C02808556', '(T561041A C72/59460)>POPMigr.T576447A,C72/221816*3C00721502')

dt <- data.frame(x,y,z)

charLoc <- str_locate(pattern = "3C", dt$z)
idx <- list()
for (s in 1:dim(charLoc)[1]) {
  idx[s] <- substring(dt$z[s], first = charLoc[s,][1], last = charLoc[s,][1]+9)
}
dt$val <- sapply(idx, paste0, collapse=",")
print(head(dt))
```

and the output of the same is

```
  x y                                                           z        val
1 1 T                                       3C00652722 (T558799A) 3C00652722
2 2 T                           NA >> MSP: T0578836A & 3C03024632 3C03024632
3 3 T                         T0579010A, 3C03051500, EAET03051496 3C03051500
4 4 U                     T0023231A > MSP: T0577506A & 3C02808556 3C02808556
5 8 U (T561041A C72/59460)>POPMigr.T576447A,C72/221816*3C00721502 3C00721502
```